# Google JavaScript Table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Is possible to make this script take MySQL data? Can anybody show me?

This script is from google chars, table ... I try to make this script take MySQL data and display in a table.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['table']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);
      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='table_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, does this code work?  Not work?  What part of this are you stuck on?  Getting the MySQL data?  Putting in the script?  Making a table?  What do you need help with?

Comment: This seems like a fairly simple problem. Have you made any attempts yet? Basically you just need to write some PHP to get the data from MySQL and print it out on the page as a JSON. the javascript code will then use that data in the `addRows` method

Comment: i can' update it https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

Answer (score 2):

just fill your php array with values like this

```
$array = array(
    array(
        array('01', array('v' => 10000, 'f' => '$10,000'), 'Mike'),
        ...
        array('12', array('v' => 12500, 'f' => '$12,200'), 'Mike'),
    )
);
```

then in your HTML code write :

```
/* code starts here ... */
function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'ID');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salariu');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addRows(<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true});
      }

/* rest of code */
```

**UPDATE**

You have updated your source code and the addRows method argument format has changed, This how you should fill your php array (Drop the global array);

```
$array = array(
    array('01', array('v' => 10000, 'f' => '$10,000'), 'Mike'),
    ...
    array('12', array('v' => 12500, 'f' => '$12,200'), 'Mike'),
);
```

**UPDATE 2** Help with mysql data retrieving

```
$array = array();
$result = mysql_query('SELECT f1, f2, f3, f4 FROM some_table');
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = array($row['f1'], array('v' => $row['f2'], 'f' => $row['f3']), $row['f4']);
}
```

//Your array is now filled

Hope it helps

Comment: i understent that but i dont know how to make this javascript take mysql data

Comment: Just fill your array with that format using your mysql data. I will update my answer another time.